# Sharepoint 2013 center title of list

Tags: css, sharepoint, css-tables

I created a list in Sharepoint but I can not center the title of my columns . For cell contents I added a component with a change in the CSS:

```
td
{
  text-align:center;
}
```

How do the column headings ?

Comment: You created a list (backend), this has nothing to do with front-end styles. What do you actually mean by 'list'?

Comment: @dayuloli He simply wants to center a column header, from my understanding...  Not sure what that has to do with sharepoint, but yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the header and apply a `text-align:center;`:

```
.ms-listviewtable tr.ms-viewheadertr th {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Or just center all headers:

```
th {
   text-align:center;
}
```